# Issue with infinite loop for determining if a word is palindrome

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Programming Task 1</title>
</head>

<body>
 <script>
 var x, pall, word1;
 word1 = prompt("Please enter a word and i will determine if its a palindrome or not")
 x = 0
 while( x <= word1.length / 2)( pall == true)
    if (word1.length(x)!= word1.charAt(word1.length - 1 - x)){
        pall == false
    }

    x=x+1;
 if (pall == true) {
    confirm("the word you entered "+ word1 + " is a palindrome")
 }
 else
 {
    confirm("the word you entered " + word1 + " is not a palindrome")
 }
 </script> 

</body>

</html>
```

this is what i have currently. this is designed for a website to determine a Palindrome and im unsure why but the loop doesnt stop and im only beginning to code any help is appreciated

Comment: The only statement in the `while` loop is `pall == true`, because you've haven't enclosed anything in curly braces.

Comment: Um, what is this? `while( x <= word1.length / 2)( pall == true)`

Comment: This is actually a great opportunity to use your browser's debugging tools.  Take a look at the code debugger where you can place a breakpoint in the code so it will pause during execution, then step through the code line by line as it executes and observe what it does.  How does that behavior differ from what you're expecting?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have to use a loop? There's an easier way to do this with javascript:

```
var s1 = 'racecar';
var s2 = 'notracecar';

function isPalindrome(string){
    return string.split('').reverse().join('') == string;
}

isPalindrome(s1);
isPalindrome(s2);
```

Comment: thx i used  this but in a bit different because it wouldnt give the me correct answer and was having trouble so i changed it to this

 s1 = prompt("Please enter a word and i will determine if its a palindrome or not");

 s2 = s1.split("");

 s3 = s2.reverse();

 s4 = s3.join("");